# formatting MySQL output to valid CSV or XLSX

Tags: mysql, csv, xlsx

I have a query whose output I format and dump onto a CSV file.

This is the code I'm using,

```
(query.....)
INTO OUTFILE
    "/tmp/dump.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY
    ','
ENCLOSED BY
    '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY
    '\n'
;
```

However when I open the CSV in Google Sheets or Excel, the columns are broken up into hundreds of smaller ones.

When I open the CSV in a plain text editor, I see that the column values itself contain quotes (single and double), commas, line-breaks.
Only the double-quotes are escaped.

Even though the double-quotes are escaped, they are omitted when interpreted by Google Sheets and Excel.
I tried manually editing the CSV entries; escaping the commas and such. But no luck. The commas still break the columns. However, in a couple of instances they didn't break the column. I am not able to figure why though.

So my question is how do I correctly format the output to accommodate for these characters and dump it onto a CSV or even an XLXS ( in case a CSV is not capable for situations like these )?

For context, I'm operating in a WordPress environment. If there is a solution in PHP, that can work too.

EDIT ::

Here is a sample line from the CSV,

```
"1369","Blaze Pannier Mounts for KTM Duke 200 & 390","HTA.04.740.80200/B","<strong>Product Description</strong><span data-sheets-value=\"[null,2,&quot;SW Motech brings you the Blaze Pannier Brackets for the Duke 200 &amp; 390. &quot;]\" data-sheets-userformat=\"[null,null,15293,[null,0],11]\">SW Motech brings you the Blaze Pannier Brackets for the Duke 200 &amp; 390.</span>","&nbsp;<strong>What's in the box? </strong><span data-sheets-value=\"[null,2,&quot;2 Quick Lock SupportsnMounting materialnMounting Instructions&quot;]\" data-sheets-userformat=\"[null,null,15293,[null,0],null,[null,[[null,2,0,null,null,[null,2,13421772]],[null,0,0,3],[null,1,0,null,1]]],[null,[[null,2,0,null,null,[null,2,13421772]],[null,0,0,3],[null,1,0,null,1]]],[null,[[null,2,0,null,null,[null,2,13421772]],[null,0,0,3],[null,1,0,null,1]]],[null,[[null,2,0,null,null,[null,2,13421772]],[null,0,0,3],[null,1,0,null,1]]],null,0,1,0,null,[null,2,0],&quot;calibri,arial,sans,sans-serif&quot;,11]\">2 Quick Lock SupportsMounting materialMounting Instructions</span>&nbsp;","<a href=\"http://shop.sw-motech.com/cosmoshop/artikelpdf/bc_hta_04_740_10200_b.pdf\" target=\"_blank\">Installation Instructions</a>"
```

Comment: Can you show us 1-2 rows of the current CSV output?

Comment: Try removing `ENCLOSED BY '"'` which may be causing problems in Excel.

Comment: added a sample line; see EDIT

Comment: Please try getting rid of the quotes around each field.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the suggestion, but getting rid of the quotes didn't work. According to [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180), correctly formatted CSV files require that double-quotes within a field be escaped with a double-quote itself. Also, if a field has commas or line-breaks, then the entire field should be enclosed within double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

From [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.  For example:

> ```
>   "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```

Any double quotes inside fields enclosed with double quotes need to be escaped with another double quote. So given `abc,ab"c,"` the expected formatting would be `abc,"ab""c",""""`.

Comment: Thanks for the CSV reference! I eventually used "awk" to format the output from MySQL. To simplify things, I used a custom field and row delimiter when outputting from MySQL. This is because some column values even had line breaks besides commas and double-quotes.

Comment: You're welcome! For some reason I didn't explicitly say it but using the same csv you provided I was able to import it into Excel without any issue after escaping the double quotes with double quotes. Using custom delimiters works as well of course :)